# Writing a subroutine that receives an 8 bit number

Tags: assembly, subroutine

This is a homework question I recently encounter..
Write a subroutine called twoscom that receives an 8 bit number A as an argument and returns an 8 bit value correspodning to the two's complement of A. Any idea how to do this? :/
Test it with 8F base 16

Comment: I think it assembly language program. I'm supposed to write the instruction down and try it out later in HS12 ?

Comment: If this is homework please identify it as such.

Comment: There are many different assembly languages.

Comment: Hint: why do we use twos complement?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the most processors are already encoded as two's complement and there is no need to "convert" them. And in general, "two's complement" is a human interpretation of the numbers.

Another deal is if you want to compute the negative number of the given (that is what two's complement actually is) i.e. you need y = -x.

In many platforms such easy operation is implemented by special instruction and there is no need to use a function:

```
; x86
    neg al
```

On the CPUs where **neg** instruction is not available it is still very easy to be implemented by 2 instructions:

```
; pseudo cpu
    not reg8
    inc reg8

; or 
    xor reg8, 0ffh
    add reg8, 1

; or any other combination available
```

Why this operation is not suitable to be implemented as a subroutine? Such subroutine will look like:

```
; al contains the argument and return the result.
twoscom:
      neg al
      ret
```

Then if you want to use it to compute the two's complement of cl, you have to:

```
      mov  al, cl
      call twoscom
```

This way you execute 4 instructions that are 8 bytes long on 16bit program and 10bytes on 32bit, and what is worse, affect memory read write (stack operations of call/ret) instead of single instruction:

```
      neg cl    ; always 2 bytes and memory access.
```

Two's complement is simply very very basic operation. You will not write subroutine to add two numbers, are you?

Comment: what is the different it will be if I were asked to use subroutine instead of "write an assembly language program?" I am trying to understand subroutine and still a little bit confused

Comment: answer edited, with explanation why it is not suitable to make this code as a subroutine.

Comment: what is the target platform

Comment: hs12 is it possible that i email you my answer?

Comment: Isn't it HC12? Anyway, I don't know this CPU. Nevertheless, it should be as simple as the above examples.